# Layout nesting in JsRender on server-side

Tags: node.js, jsrender

Is it possible to organize views and layouts in Node.JS with JsRender & Express as rendering mechanism like on below image?

Each part of webpage is separate file, and during rendering you are deciding which one to use...

[image: Layout organizing with JsRender]

Answer (score 2):

Yes - did you look at:

- http://www.jsviews.com/#jsr-node-quickstart
- http://www.jsviews.com/#node/filetmpls (including where it talks about nested templates).

The samples here: https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender-node-starter show both nested layouts on the server and in the browser. For example, this line
https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender-node-starter/blob/master/templates/layout-movies.html#L34 is doing server template composition: `{{include tmpl='./templates/movie-list.html'/}}` within the layout-movies template.

You can also do dynamic composition based on (server) render-time data or context - since you can set `tmpl=...` to any expression. For example:

- `{{include tmpl=type==='a' ? '.../a.html': '.../default.html'/}}`

or

- `{{include tmpl=~getTmpl(type)/}}`

where `~getTmpl()` is a helper which you could define like this:

```
jsrender.views.helpers("getTmpl", function(type) {
  switch (type) {
    case "major":
      return "./templates/major.html";
  }
  return "./templates/base.html";
});
```

You could have `~getTmpl()` return actual compiled templates, rather than file paths to templates, if you want, for example by writing

```
return jsrender.templates("./templates/major.html");
```